# CSS can't check for focus

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in html:

```
<nav class="box">
    <div class="logo">
        <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx linksbuendig">
            <span>toggle menu</span>
        </button>(...)
    </div>
</nav>

    <div class="relative box">

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and this in CSS:

```
.c-hamburger:focus ~ div.nav {
margin:0;}
```

so if the button is focused the div should change the margin. But it won't work, until i copy the code for the button 1 to 1 directly over the div with the class nav. Why does it so and what can I change? Just copy solves the problem until now, but then is the full page destroyed, because there're other elements in between etc.
JS or sth. like that is not allowed. Please only CSS resp HTML.
Beforehand: Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: `div.nav` is not a sibling of `.c-hamburger`

Comment: @Quantastical ok, sounds logic, but is there a way to change that? Or do you know other possibilities to realise that (only with CSS and HTML)?

Comment: It is not possible with just CSS.